# Check if string contains single backslashes with regex

Tags: regex, scala, backslash

I have tried to fix this for a long time, and i just can't do it.

It could be any string, but this is an example:

```
"\This string \contains some\ backslashes\"
```

I need to make a regex that i can use to check that the string contains single backslashes.

I then need to convert the given string into (i can do the conversion):

```
"\\This string \\contains some\\ backslashes\\"
```

And then use regex to check that the string no long contains single backslashes.

Btw i dont have to use regex for this, i just need to be able to check the strings somehow.

Comment: I believe you cannot do that, because these escaped characters are processed by the compiler and are gone by the time program is running. Afaik, you  cannot detect what was the "original" form of the string literal in the source code.

Comment: Look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/If2U83). It might give you ideas or clarify our (mis)understanding of your question.

Comment: I don't really know how to formulate the problem in another way. I just need a regex to check if a string contains single backslashes. What i've come up with so far is a regex looking like this: [^\\\]\\\[^\\\] but it doesnt find the backslashes beginning and ending the string.

Comment: Ok, try `.replaceAll("""(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)""", """\\\\""")`. Does that work for you? Or do you just need the `(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)` regex for any other check?

Comment: Also, if you need to check if a string contains a single backslash, you might use something like  https://ideone.com/P1SXII.

Comment: Then let me post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just want to check if a string matches a regex pattern partially, namely, if it contains a literal backslash not preceded nor followed with a backslash.

Use

```
(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uWwyU3/1).

Sample Scala code:

```
val s = """"\This string\\ \contains some\ backslashes\""""
val rx = """(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)""".r.unanchored
val ismatch = s match {
  case rx(_*) => true
  case _ => false
}
println(ismatch)
```

See the [Scala online demo](https://ideone.com/P1SXII).

Note:

- `"""(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)""".r.unanchored` - this line declares a regex object and makes the pattern unanchored, so that no full string match is no longer required by the `match` block
- Inside `match`, we use `case rx(_*)` as there is no capturing group defined inside the pattern itself
- The pattern means: match a backslash (`\\`) that is not preceded with a backslash (`(?<!\\)`) and is not followed with a backslash (`(?!\\)`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking.. are you asking how to write a String literal that represents the String you gave as an example? You could either escape the backslash with another backslash, or use triple quotes.

```
scala> "\\This string \\contains some\\ backslashes\\"
String = \This string \contains some\ backslashes\

scala> """\This string \contains some\ backslashes\"""
String = \This string \contains some\ backslashes\
```

And replace the backslashes using the same techniques.

```
scala> "\\This string \\contains some\\ backslashes\\".replace("\\","\\\\")
String = \\This string \\contains some\\ backslashes\\
```

or

```
scala> """\This string \contains some\ backslashes\""".replace("""\""","""\\""")
String = \\This string \\contains some\\ backslashes\\
```

But I have a feeling you want to do something else, like validate input. Maybe you could provide a bit more context?

Comment: I have created a method that does the conversion of the string. I need the regex (or some other way to test it) to unit test this method. So before i call the method in my unit test i want to make sure the input string contains single backslashes, and then after the method call on the string i want to check that all occurrences of single backslashes has been replaced by double backslashes. I think i suck at explaining the problem :P

Comment: Conversion of the string? Convert from what to what? And also, it seems String's contains method, as in "abdc".contains("\\") is not working for you? Are you getting errors or unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
val s = """\This string \contains some\ backslashes\"""

s.replaceAll("""\\""","""\\\\""")
```